# Eclipse - SVN derived files are committed in background

Tags: eclipse, svn, commit, ignore, derived

I have several projects in eclipse and sometimes I mark a file as derived so SVN ignores the file and it doesn't get committed. For a while this worked for me but somehow I have some problems now. Some of these files get committed from my account. Svn history tells me that I did commit those files but I'm 100% sure I did not.

I have 3 files committed in the history but the dialog did only show 2 of them. Is there a problem when I put versioned files on derived ? So they somehow get committed in the background ? Because that's what it looks like to me. I never saw those files in my commit dialogue but Eclipse (4.2.1) Subversive (SVNKit 1.7.5v1) did commit them somehow.

Is there a better way to ignore those files in further commits ? They need to be in version control and I do have some local changes to these files who shouldn't be committed. So svn ignore is not an option.